# Java Nullpointer exception while reading properties file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Getting below java null pointer exception when reading the Config.properties file.
LoginTest.java extends TestBase.java and calls the TestBase constructor for loading config properties and calls initializeTestBase method for getting properties from config file. 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.crm.testbase.TestBase.initializeTestBase(TestBase.java:35)

[TestBase.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHFMG.jpg)

```
public class TestBase {
  public static WebDriver driver;
  public static Properties prop;
  public TestBase() 
  {
    try
    {
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      FileInputStream fp = new FileInputStream("E:\\Photon WorkSpace\\My_DD_FRAMEWORK"
        + "\\src\\main\\java\\com\\crm\\config\\Config.properties");
      prop.load(fp);
      System.out.println("printing config="+prop.getProperty("browser"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void initializeTestBase()
  {
    String browser=prop.getProperty("browser");
    System.out.println("printg initilaz test base browser"+ prop.getProperty("browser"));
    if(browser.equals("chrome"))
    {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium Jar\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
  }
}
```

[LoginTest.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTOHX.jpg)

```
public class LoginTest extends TestBase{
  LoginPage loginPage;
  HomePage hp;
  public  LoginTest()
  {
    super();
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void setup()
  {
    System.out.println("calling initalize base");
    initializeTestBase();
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
  }
}
```

[Config.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiHzf.jpg)

```
browser=chrome
user=mytest
password=test
url=https://classic.mycrm.com/index.html
```

[Nullpointer exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTfvo.jpg)

```
RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.11.0
printing config=chrome
calling initalize base
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setup
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.crm.testbase.TestBase.initializeTestBase(TestBase.java:30)
at com.crm.testcases.LoginTest.setup(LoginTest.java:24)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: added Java code snippet

Comment: There is no folder src/main/java if you running your code. Try class.getResourse().  Btw property files should be in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 2):

In TestBase.java, you have a static variable named `prop` that isn't initialized.

Then, down inside your try block in your constructor, you do this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
```

That creates a *new* local variable named `prop` that shadows the static variable, and does not modify the static `prop` variable at all, so it remains null.  All operations in that try block that reference `prop` are using that local variable, and not the static variable.

Then, when you get to

```
String browser=prop.getProperty("browser");
```

You try to call a method off of that null variable, which results in the exception that you're seeing.

The solution is to change the constructor to have:

```
prop = new Properties()
```